# Getting two different HashKeys with different methods

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using two different methods to get the HashKey to connect an application to Facebook SDK.  Although I got it connected with one of the responses I am curious to see why I am getting different results.

**Working result I am generating the Key Hash within the application**

```
public class GetHashKey extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_hash_key);
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;

                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Other method terminal giving me the wrong result**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\keytool" -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Eugene\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

I am assuming I am doing it incorrectly. If anyone sees a solution to get it through the terminal that would be very helpful!

**Update** This is the windows command to get the HashKey provided by facebook

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: Isn't the last command supposed to be `"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" enc -base64`?

Comment: @TedHopp Just updated my question with the command provided by facebook

Comment: So that command sequence works and your problem is solved?

Comment: @TedHopp That is giving me the non working HashKey.

Comment: Hm. Are you sure that the code version is running with the same debug key? Or is it signed with your production key?

Comment: @TedHopp I am not completely sure.  Any suggestion on how I would know whether the code version is running with the same debug key?

Comment: Well, are you exporting the project? That usually signs it with your production key. You can also try modifying the command line to export your production key (you'll probably have to change the keystore as well as the alias).

Comment: @TedHopp I figured it was the signing when you export the project.  I have no exported the project yet.  It is just for test purposed.